# How to set all scalar types (number/boolean/string etc) to be set to type "string" during dynamic mapping (using river plugin)

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

This might be something really peculiar I'm trying to do. I'm running a "river" to dynamically index all data in my couchdb.
As multiple users enter data into the system, sometimes there is a conflict in mapping (`MapperParser Error`). For example:

- **userA** adds the following data - `{"tweet" : {"fooval" : "1"}}` 
  -- elasticSearch creates a Mapping for this `tweet.fooval` variable as **Number** (as it interprets it as a number)
- **userB** adds the following data - `{"tweet" : {"fooval" : "false"}}` 
  -- elasticSearch tries to create a Mapping for this `tweet.fooval` variable as **Boolean** (as it interprets it as a Boolean) and **hence a MapperParser Error**.

I guess you see the problem. Also I only want to do it at the level of scalar types, as I don't want Arrays/Objects to be treated as strings. I want all scalar types to be treated as Strings while the mapping is being created.

I couldn't find anything on the doc page, or on the forum, so thought will ask here for directions/pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by default, elasticsearch is not parsing strings. So, if you will pass to elasticsearch the following JSON: `{"tweet": {"fooval": "1"}}` it will treat `tweet.fooval` as a string. If elaticsearch is parsing strings, make sure that `numeric_detection` and `date_detection` are set to false in the [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/root-object-type.html).

On the other side, if elasticsearch receives a value as a JSON number like this: `{"tweet": {"fooval": 1}}`, elasticsearch will indeed map such field as long or double. You can override this behavior by using dynamic_templates. Here is an example:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-idx -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
        "index.number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "dynamic_templates" : [
                {
                    "template_obj" : {
                        "match" : "*",
                        "match_mapping_type" : "object",
                        "mapping" : {
                            "type" : "object"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "template_str" : {
                        "match" : "*",
                        "mapping" : {
                            "type" : "string"
                        }
                    }
                }            
            ]
        }
    }
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/1 -d '{
    "count": 123,
    "sold": false,
    "date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "price": 12.3,
    "description": {
        "weight":  42.3,
        "size": {
            "lenght": 30,
            "width": 20,
            "hight": 10
        }
    }
}'
echo
curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/_mapping?pretty=true"
```

Comment: Can I use dynamic templates trick with river plugin? Once I set the mapping using dynamic templates, the river fails to start.

[2013-01-16 13:35:35,818][WARN ][river                    ] [Starsmore, Jonothon] failed to create river [test][test]
org.elasticsearch.common.settings.NoClassSettingsException: Failed to load class with value [test]

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use dynamic templates with a river. Just create the index first, or use [Index Templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-templates.html) to make sure that dynamic templates are applied. The error that you are getting indicates that you are trying to create a river with type `test`. Unless you wrote a river plugin with type test yourself, you probably specified wrong type for your river.

Comment: ok, so here's what I'm doing:

curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/_river/tempTest/'

curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/tempTest/'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tempTest -d '{"mappings":{"tempTest":{"dynamic_templates":[{"template_obj":{"match":"*","match_mapping_type":"object","mapping":{"type":"object"}}},{"template_str":{"match":"*","mapping":{"type":"string"}}}]}}}'

Comment: `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/tempTest/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "tempTest",
        "couchdb" : {
            "host" : "localhost",
            "port" : 5984,
            "db" : "tempTest",
            "filter" : null
            },
        "index" : {
            "index" : "tempTest",
            "type" : "tempTest",
            "bulk_size" : "100",
            "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
            }
}'`

Comment: sorry to break it into multiple comments, but the limit of the text in a comment made me do that and it isnt accepting `code` properly in comments either.

Basically I first delete any previous indices/rivers for my test db -here i have named it "tempTest"

Then, I follow your trick of dynamic templates to specify a setting whereby everything other than objects is treated as string.
and then I try to create a river on that index 
Note that by virtue of creating mapping, I already have created the index. Its at the step of creating the river that I get that error.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think the fact that you cannot fit it into one comment might be a good indicator that this issue deserves creation of a separate question. ;)

Comment: Here is the newer question. I would really appreciate your help on it!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366429/unable-to-create-elasticsearch-river-on-couchdb-using-dynamic-template-mappings

Comment: Hey, while using these mappings, I get errors when it I give it an empty object. I get something like this:

message [MapperParsingException[object mapping for [foo] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?]]

Any idea about how to avoid that?

Comment: You probably tried to give it an empty string `"foo":""`, not an empty object `"foo":{}`. The first one fails, because it tries to parse string `""` as an object. The second one works just fine. I cannot think of a way around it.

Comment: I gave the second one - "foo" :{}, but yes I see my db adds an extra line (End of File character) which is causing the issue.. Is there a way to skip that..?